# Update lower and upper bounds in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5

I have a table (12 rows) in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database with two columns ID and geometry. Table structure from PgAdmin3 is:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table
(
id integer,
geom geometry
)
```

The geometry represents triangles starting from true north having ID as 1 and so on. The ID for each row is unique i.e., 1 - 12. Based on this ID, I am trying to update angles and their lower and upper bounds. My approach has been:

```
Select
id,
Case    when id = 1 then 30
        when id = 2 then 60
        when id = 3 then 90
        when id = 4 then 120
        when id = 5 then 150 
        when id = 6 then 180
        when id = 7 then 210 
        when id = 8 then 240 
        when id = 9 then 270
        when id = 10 then 300
        when id = 11 then 330
        when id = 12 then 360
end as angle,
case    when id = 1 then lower(numrange(0, 30))
        when id = 2 then lower(numrange(30, 60))
        when id = 3 then lower(numrange(60, 90))
        when id = 4 then lower(numrange(90, 120))
        when id = 5 then lower(numrange(120, 150))
        when id = 6 then lower(numrange(150, 180))
        when id = 7 then lower(numrange(180, 210))
        when id = 8 then lower(numrange(210, 240))
        when id = 9 then lower(numrange(240, 270))
        when id = 10 then lower(numrange(270, 300))
        when id = 11 then lower(numrange(300, 330))
        when id = 12 then lower(numrange(330, 360))
end as lb
from my_table
```

Is there a better way to do this? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please add table definition to the post

Comment: @VaoTsun: Please see edit. Added table structure from pgAdmin3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first I thought to use window function here, but then I realized that you dont need ANY column from my_table for this. Try:

**updated** to reflect notes from OP (note, that you will need to define lowest boundary explicitly - here I used zero)

```
t=# with p as (select id,angle from generate_series(30,360,30) with ordinality as g(angle,id)) select *,coalesce(lag(angle) over (order by id),0) lb from p;
 id | angle | lb
----+-------+-----
  1 |    30 |   0
  2 |    60 |  30
  3 |    90 |  60
  4 |   120 |  90
  5 |   150 | 120
  6 |   180 | 150
  7 |   210 | 180
  8 |   240 | 210
  9 |   270 | 240
 10 |   300 | 270
 11 |   330 | 300
 12 |   360 | 330
(12 rows)
```

**update**
rewrite OP query I'd use CTE to avoid listing cases in window function:

```
t=# with a as (Select
id,
Case    when id = 1 then 30
        when id = 2 then 60
        when id = 3 then 90
        when id = 4 then 120
        when id = 5 then 150
        when id = 6 then 180
        when id = 7 then 210
        when id = 8 then 240
        when id = 9 then 270
        when id = 10 then 300
        when id = 11 then 330
        when id = 12 then 360
end as angle
from my_table)
select *,coalesce(lag(angle) over (order by id),0)
from a;
 id | angle | coalesce
----+-------+----------
  1 |    30 |        0
  2 |    60 |       30
  3 |    90 |       60
  4 |   120 |       90
  5 |   150 |      120
  6 |   180 |      150
  7 |   210 |      180
  8 |   240 |      210
  9 |   270 |      240
 10 |   300 |      270
 11 |   330 |      300
 12 |   360 |      330
(12 rows)

Time: 0.462 ms
```

Comment: This worked but please note that I need to update my_table i.e, to generate angles, lower bound and upper bounds of triangles based on IDs. That's why I used CASE statement for IDs. Alternatively, I would need to make a join between "g" (your proposed solution) and my_table. Correct?

Comment: Probably, using window function over ID column could be a better approach?

Comment: yes - if you have angles not growing by 30, you need to bond id to angle values and then use lead() or lag() over ()

Comment: That's why I asked for a better approach :). Maybe you may consider to update your answer.

Comment: updated to use `lag()`, so you could use different steps

Comment: +1 for that! Thank you. I wonder why you are not making selection of ID from my_table? just a quick question. Because, I will need to join this result to the ID of my_table. I prefer not to join by the way.

Comment: my hand rejects copy/paste 12 `case when` , sorry :)

Comment: Lol :) that makes sense at least. But you know what I needed to work on ID column of my_table. Sorry from my side as well if this bothers you :)

Comment: and probably you could have retained your previous answer as well. There could be several approaches to do one task and that's what question was asking for the better approach.

Comment: Thank you so much!